# Block access to TFS during update?

Tags: update, team-foundation-server

We have a TFS Server running TFS 2015 RTW. We really [ought to update it](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/productinfo/vs-servicing-vs#for-visual-studio-and-team-foundation-server-2012---2017) and plan to do so next week.

We'll be performing the update during normal working hours in order to ensure there are plenty of "fire fighters" available if anything goes awry, and we're planning as low an impact update as possible - moving to update 4 rather than upgrading to a later version at this time.

The concern is that, despite emailing all parties who make use of the server, someone could attempt to access the server whilst the update is in progress or, worse, after we've updated and whilst we're still evaluating whether the update is a success or if we need to roll it back.

Is there a smart way to limit access to TFS during the update process? We actually access the server via some DNS aliases (tfs.example.com and data.tfs.example.com for the app tier and data tier respectively) and I'd considered repointing these aliases somewhere else during the update. But then remembered the TFS itself "knows" these aliases - e.g. the Notification URL and Web Access URL use the first alias, so I'd be concerned that changing them could affect the outcome of the update.

So is there something else I can do, beyond making sure the email is really sternly worded?

Comment: Block connections via a firewall?

Comment: @gf_ - I'm not sure if we've got a firewall in the right place (our network is still quite open), but along similar lines, I'm now looking at the IIS IP Restictions functionality.

Comment: I'm not really into the Windows world, but this runs on Windows Server, right? If so, I'm quite sure there is a firewall on board.

Comment: @gf_ - there is, but it's disabled through group policy. It's a not-too-uncommon setup that all of the machines on the internal network are domain joined with no firewalls between them.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up changing settings for the "Team Foundation Server" site in IIS, to restrict which IP addresses could contact the site.

In IIS Manager, after selecting the site, under the IIS Area I select "IP Address and Domain Restrictions". I added Allow Entries for the servers own IP address and the loopback address, as well as the IP Address for my own machine from which I would perform acceptance testing. I then edited the feature settings such that unspecified clients were Denied rather than Allowed, and then confirmed that TFS itself could only be accessed from the application server itself and from my machine.

I was less concerned about people accessing the Sharepoint or Reporting Services sites relating to TFS during the upgrade since in our setup, these are mostly ignored, but similar restrictions could have been applied to these sites also.

**However**, it should be noted that during the update, the "Team Foundation Server" IIS Site is recreated; and so I had to perform the same changes a second time, and there was a small window of opportunity where someone could have accessed the newly updated service.

So this isn't 100% bulletproof.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you plan an *in-place* upgrade and you are running SQL Server 2014. If it is so, the steps are:

1. stop TFS using `TFSServiceControl quiesce`
2. run full backup using `TFSBackup` or via the Admin Console
3. install the new TFS on the Application Tier (AT)
4. run the Upgrade Wizard

Step 1 will completely stop TFS and none will be able to access it except through local admin tools.
Step 4 goes through some stages: first will configure the AT then schedule the Upgrade Jobs. TFS will be up and running and the end of the first stage but the Collections will not be available until the upgrade job has finished with them, so the smaller Collections will be on-line sooner.

Comment: We want to run some sanity checks after the update is completed to decide *whether we're happy with it or want to roll back*. During that period, we want to strictly control *who* accesses the server so that nobody e.g. checks in a valuable chunk of code and then deletes their local copy. That's what my question is looking for.